# What's the best way to solder these fine pitched connectors/pins?

Tags: soldering, pcb-assembly

During a replacement of a camera mother board, I managed to screw up one of the ribbon connectors, by tearing it right where the ribbon slides into female slot. I am unable to find any replacement ribbon cables.

So what I did was I removed the plastic housing and exposed the pins themselves and plan on running wires from the traces on the ribbon cable to these connectors.

Problem: The pins are very close to each other and thin. How can I increase my chances of success ?

Pic:
[image]

I am planning on ordering a very sharp solder tip and 40 AWG enamelled copper wire and giving it a go. Any suggestions?

Comment: Circle the part of the PCB you are talking about.

Comment: Good luck! I wont say it is impossible, but it will be challenging. I would suggest you get a syringe of flux gel as this helps to stop the solder bridging. Nothing ventured, nothing gained!

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, but there's a red arrow pointing to the pins at 6'0clock.

Comment: That pitch looks rather enormous to me. 1.27mm? You could go with 24AWG or even 22AWG. 40 is very thin.

Comment: That's the phone camera doing it's magic, you definitely need to bring the board right up against your eyes

Comment: Small soldering tip, magnifying glass, and a steady hand.  FYI, we had an operator manually solder a leaded FPGA package down with 25 mil lead spacing.  The rest of the board, SMT, was done with a standard reflow operation.  So 50 mil pitch pins (which may be what you have) is definitely doable.

Comment: You’ll enjoy using a microscope, and if one isn’t handy a webcam can be opened up and the lens can be screwed outwards to make it focus  on near objects - instant digital microscope.

Comment: I like wire wrap wires for things like this, prepared with solder and then fixed without additional solder.

Comment: Yes, wire wrapping wire is my favorite.

Comment: AWG30 (wire-wrap Kynar insulation or solder-through polyester insulated magnet wire) is about right for this job. AWG40 is very thin and if you actually got enamel it would be difficult to strip.  AWG30 is about 0.25mm diameter vs. 0.08mm for AWG40.

Comment: These aren't usually called ribbon cables but flat flex cables (FFC). They are available from many vendors. The sane solution is to replace the FFC and the connector as well, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First...did you check Digikey or Mouser for replacement cables? Even if you can't find a replacement, soldering a through-hole FPC flex cable of the correct pitch is going to be infinitely easier than soldering loose 40AWG wire.

I personally think magnet wire is going to give you trouble trying to solder through the enamel while also aiming for the pad without burning something. I have never been able to reliably solder through so-called solderable magnet wire. Also makes nasty fumes. I find it safer to just strip wire wrap wire. But if you do go magnet wire, strip the insulation first with sandpaper or acid or however you want to go about it. Don't try to solder through it.

You probably do not want a sharp tip but a small bevel/oval/hoof tip that can hold a solder bead on the end so do not need a hand holding solder wire. Add external flux and let the solder wet where it will.

The ones with a flat face and no tinning on the sides are best, followed by the bevel tips with a cup ground into them, followed by a flat faced bevel tip with tinning on the sides.

Comment: This is connector I removed:https://imgur.com/i13WO5A.png I don't know how to figure out the pitch. Are you able to tell

Comment: You would need calipers

Comment: @smooth_smoothie Caliper -> measure center to center from the two outer-most pins -> divide by the number of signals.